# Nokugiri web scrape issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, web-scraping

Seeming as i didn't ask this very well the first time. Heres another go.

I'm trying to follow this tutorial here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/190-screen-scraping-with-nokogiri

I'm currently also trying to scrape the price from this website link here: http://www.ticketmaster.co.uk/derren-brown-miracle-glasgow-04-07-2016/event/370050789149169E?artistid=1408737&majorcatid=10002&minorcatid=53&tpab=-1

What i'm wanting to achieve is to have all three of these ticket (name and price hopefully as much information about the tickets/prices as possible) and use them in my web application.

I can't show you the result, Its stupidly big in size, But i can tell you that i don't hit the second byebug, Heres my code.

```
  url = "http://www.ticketmaster.co.uk/derren-brown-miracle-glasgow-04-07-2016/event/370050789149169E?artistid=1408737&majorcatid=10002&minorcatid=53&tpab=-1"
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
    byebug
    doc.css(".item").each do |item|
      title = item.at_css(".fru").text
      byebug
    end
```

Unfortunately to help you'll ideally have to try this yourself to see the horrible page size! haha!

Edit, Ok baring in mind my screen is 27 inches, The text FILLS the screen

Heres an image of what i got in from the first image.

[image: huge image of response]

Further to this i believe that this image here is all i need? its just getting it out.

[image: what i might need!]

Thanks
Sam

Comment: images could be a good source too.

Comment: ha didnt think of an image! one second

Comment: Hey, I added an answer to your issue. It is enought to get you started. let me know if that helped. happy coding !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue here is that the price is written inside javascript and not html itslef. Nokogiri only parse XML and HTML, therefore you need help of awesome REGEX. Before you read the full code, here a few tips to undestand it.

First I search for all tags named `<script>` by using this code:

`doc.xpath("//script[@type='text/javascript']/text()").each`

It returns more than 100 objects, so I needed to find in which of them I can find the name and the price. Therefore I found out that specific javascript I needed to read had some unique text in it, so I looped through all >100 objects and tested if it contains that unique string. Here are the images for you to understand:

[image]

[image]

And when I found those peaces, I just used REGEX to extract the price and name. Here is the working code. Just copy paste and run it.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

def get_name_and_price
  ticketmaster_url = "http://www.ticketmaster.co.uk/derren-brown-miracle-glasgow-04-07-2016/event/370050789149169E?artistid=1408737&majorcatid=10002&minorcatid=53&tpab=-1"
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open( ticketmaster_url ))
  event_name = nil
  ticket_price = nil
  doc.xpath("//script[@type='text/javascript']/text()").each do |text|
    if text.content =~ /TM\.Tracking\.satellite/
      event_name = text.content[/"eventName":".*?"/].gsub!('"eventName":', '').gsub!('"', '')
    elsif text.content =~ /more_options_on_polling/
      ticket_price = text.content[/"total_price":"\d+\.\d+"/].gsub!('"total_price":', '').gsub!('"', '').to_f
    end
  end

  puts "Event name: " + event_name
  puts "Ticket price: " + ticket_price.to_s
end

get_name_and_price
```

Comment: Thanks for this, It'll help alot, However its only returning the ticket that is the maximum, There are 3 tickets avalible for this event. Ideally i could do with the ticket name/type and prices that show the base price and fees.

Comment: Well. That is beauty of coding. ;) I gave you the starter point. You can use regex to search all of those prices yourself. In your browser, open that page with prices and click right mouse button and choose "view page source", and search (CTRL+F) for the tickets prices. Try to understand how the other programmer encoded it into that html page. Knowledge takes time. Happy codding.

Comment: view page source, Thats what i couldn't work out >.<

Comment: Jus trealised whilst working on this its a little slow, There a way to speed this up?

Comment: Well. First thing comes to my mind is not to use '//', it forces the xPath to scan entire page. If you try "/html/head/script/text()", you can find the name of the event but not the price. =/  You could try [mechanize](http://ruby.bastardsbook.com/chapters/mechanize/) gem.

Comment: Okay, I've been playing around with it, I've managed to narrow it down, But i still get it coming back as a `<Nokogiri::XML::CDATA:0x3fe771ba064c` Could do with it being a json, I think i might have sped it up a little bit :D